# Installing CakePHP. Unable to access assets. Dont't find styles. URL Rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I'm starting developing with cakePHP, following the steps showed in the official web:http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html .

I placed the full cake folder on my web Document root. My problem comes when I try to display the welcome webpage at www.mydomain/cakephp, turning that the web isn't finding the proper path to the assets, being the web without any style.

For what I've found, this could be a problem of mod_rewrite configuration on my apache, I've tried everything the official documentation tells to do about with URL rewriting:

-Make sure that an .htaccess override is allowed and that AllowOverride is set to All for the correct DocumentRoot:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  #Order deny,allow
  #Deny from all
</Directory>
```

-Make sure you are loading mod_rewrite correctly: My htppd.conf, already has set mod_rewrite:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

I'm using an apache over Ubuntu.

Anyway, seems that url rewriting isn't working. I really don't know what to do with this issue now. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, there are a lot of posts about that issue out there. This one from bakery covers it pretty well.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/BBBThunda/2010/02/25/troubleshooting-cakephp-installation-issues-related-to-apache-2-mod_rewrite-for-beginners

If it's a problem of mod rewrite, as an additional tip, you can try running the next command on your console:

```
$ a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: I had already tried with that post, anyway I don't know why but anything worked. The command worked like a charm. Thank you! :)